# Question about $O$

Tags: limits, approximation-theory

Consider two non-negative sequences $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ and suppose that $\exists C>0, \ \forall \varepsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. 
$$\forall n \geq N, \ \ f(n)<C \cdot g(n)+n^{\varepsilon}\varepsilon .$$
Is it true to say that arbitrariness of $\varepsilon$ implies 
$$\forall n \geq N,  \ \ f(n) \leq C \cdot g(n),$$ and conserquently
$$f(n)=O(g(n)) \ \ \text{as} \ n \to \infty?$$

Answer (score 2):

Example.  $g(n) = 1$ and $f(n) = \log(n)$, $C=1$.  Then we have:
for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N>0$ such that
$$\forall n \geq N, \ \ f(n)<C \cdot g(n)+n^{\varepsilon}\varepsilon$$
But $f(n) = O(g(n))$ fails.

**added**

For every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N>0$ such that
$$\forall n \geq N, \ \ \log n < n^{-2}+n^{\varepsilon}\varepsilon$$
But $\log n = O(n^{-2})$ fails.

Comment: let me edit my question. My $C$ is independent of $\varepsilon$ and $n$.

Comment: OK $C=1$ will do.

Comment: got it. What happens if I set $g(n)=n^{-2}$, do you think the claim is true? I am confused.

Comment: so I guess what your answer suggests is that it's wrong to think $n^{\varepsilon} \to 1$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$, right?

Comment: It is wrong as long as $N$ depends on $\epsilon$.  If there is one $N$ that works for all, then you will be $OK$... but that is not very useful.